# Replace several characters from a column in a csv file in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have a csv file looking like this:

```
> collar<-read.csv("41361_predicted_by_41365_cluster.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = F)
> head(collar)
        observed      predicted probability
1 Moving/Feeding       Standing           1
2       Standing Feeding/Moving           1
3       Standing Feeding/Moving           1
4       Standing Feeding/Moving           1
5       Standing Feeding/Moving           1
6       Standing Feeding/Moving           1
```

My question is simple yet a bit difficult to implement since I'm learning R. I simply need to do the following character replacements in the column `predicted`:

1) replace `Feeding/Moving` for `Standing`

2) replace `Moving/Feeding` for `Feeding/Moving`

3) replace `Standing` for `Moving/Feeding`

I then would like to write the data in csv format using the name `"corrected_41361_predicted_by_41365_cluster"`.

I am looking for the most compact way yo do it. Is there a different way than `gsub()`? Any input is appreciated!

Comment: You didn't load each single CSV in the loop. `dfs`contains only the filenames as far as I can see, not the data itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that? (I changed your sample a little, to include "Moving/Feeding")

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(predicted = case_when(predicted == 'Feeding/Moving' ~ 'Standing',
                               predicted == 'Moving/Feeding' ~ 'Feeding/Moving',
                               predicted == 'Standing' ~ 'Moving/Feeding',
                               TRUE ~ predicted)) %>%
 write.csv(file = "corrected_41361_predicted_by_41365_cluster.csv")
```

The file contains the result:

```
        observed      predicted probability
1 Moving/Feeding Moving/Feeding           1
2       Standing       Standing           1
3       Standing       Standing           1
4       Standing       Standing           1
5       Standing Feeding/Moving           1
6       Standing       Standing           1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
# Read all files in folder
mydocpath = "C:/Users/yourdata"
files <- list.files(path=sprintf("%s",mydocpath), pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
print(files)

# Read to "list of DFs"
myf = lapply(files, function(x) data.frame(read.csv(x, sep=";", header=F, na = "na", skip=1)))
# Access single DF in list
myf[[1]]

# Do something to each DF
for(i in myf){
  print(head(myf))
}
```

Comment: Did you saw that I edited the post a few minutes ago to make it more simple?

Comment: No, haven't seen it... but there already is an answer now... :-)